# Idiomatically return a Maybe at the end of a chain

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have the following code snippet, which kinda works:

```
launchTask :: (DeviceRepo m) => TaskSpec -> m (Maybe Task)
launchTask taskSpec@TaskSpec { taskSpecImage = image
                             , taskSpecRequirement = requirement
                             } = do
  mayDevice <- getDeviceMatchingRequirement requirement
  case mayDevice of
    Nothing -> return Nothing
    Just device -> do
      mayContainer <- createContainer device requirement
      case mayContainer of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just container ->
          return $
          Just
            Task
              { taskName = pack image
              , taskStatus = TaskStatusRunning
              , taskSpec = taskSpec
              , taskContainerId = containerId container
              }
```

However, I feel that this is not very idiomatic. What's the right way to stack the main calculation (from DeviceRepo m) and perhaps a Maybe monad so that if any of the values are missing then Nothing is instantly returned?

**Edit**: My attempt with `MaybeT`, but the type doesn't match

```
launchTask2 :: (DeviceRepo m) => TaskSpec -> m (Maybe Task)
launchTask2 taskSpec@TaskSpec { taskSpecImage = image
                              , taskSpecRequirement = requirement
                              } = runMaybeT launcher
  where
    launcher :: MaybeT m Task
    launcher =
      getDeviceMatchingRequirement requirement >>= \device ->
        createContainer device requirement >>= \container ->
          return
            Task
              { taskName = pack image
              , taskStatus = TaskStatusRunning
              , taskSpec = taskSpec
              , taskContainerId = containerId container
              }
```

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Device’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe Device’
    • In the first argument of ‘createContainer’, namely ‘device’
      In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely
        ‘createContainer device requirement’
      In the expression:
        createContainer device requirement
          >>=
            \ container
              -> return
                   Task
                     {taskName = pack image, taskStatus = TaskStatusRunning,
                      taskSpec = taskSpec, taskContainerId = containerId container}
   |
58 |         createContainer device requirement >>= \container ->
   |                         ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the `MaybeT` monad transformer: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [**`MaybeT`** monad transformer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#t:MaybeT) from the [**`transformers`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers):

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe(MaybeT(MaybeT))

launchTask' :: DeviceRepo m => TaskSpec -> MaybeT m Task
launchTask' taskSpec@TaskSpec { taskSpecImage = image, taskSpecRequirement = requirement } = do
    device <- MaybeT (getDeviceMatchingRequirement requirement)
    container <- MaybeT (createContainer device requirement)
    return Task
        { taskName = pack image
        , taskStatus = TaskStatusRunning
        , taskSpec = taskSpec
        , taskContainerId = containerId container
        }
```

This is thus a function `MaybeT m Task`, you can use **`runMaybeT`** to transform the `MaybeT m a` into an `m (Maybe a)`:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe(runMaybeT)

lanchTask :: DeviceRepo m => TaskSpec -> m (Maybe Task)
launchTask = runMaybeT . lanchTask'
```